# How to use Gibbs Sampling in Stanford NER?

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I need to use Gibbs Sampling for inference in Conditional Random Fields instead of Viterbi. I saw code related to Gibbs sampling in the library, but I cannot figure out how to use it. I tried the command line with doGibbs = true, but it requires me to also input a class for priorModelFactory. However, I cannot find any class like that in the library. Any hints are appreciated!

Comment: It seems that `ListeningSequenceModel prior = getCliqueTree(newDocument);` is one option. However, I obtain significantly lower accuracy compared to using standard Viterbi. Moreover, when I run it several time, it outputs the same results, which is a little bit weird because Gibbs sampling involves some randomization. Don't know what is wrong here. Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Update: The accuracy is not that significantly lower than standard Viterbi, which is a good thing. So I guess the problem is solved.